# Excel Online automatic data fill

Tags: excel-formula, autofill, excel-online

I'm working with a file in excel online... I'm not the owner but I want to understand how it works.

There are some cells with no formula where data is automatically filled from others sheets when users type text.
How is it possible?
If I try to download the file in these cells I can see this formula (in online version there aren't):

```
=IF.ERROR(@__xludf.DUMMYFUNCTION("""COMPUTED_VALUE""");"ABC")
```

Probably is set some function that I don't know... Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 1):

Found it! It was a "QUERY()" function in the first row.